# Why I'm having problems pushing my first repo?

Tags: github

I'm trying to push my first repo to github but I got this error

> git branch -M main
> fatal: Invalid branch name: 'HEAD'

Could someone help me to fix the problem

Comment: does your github contains a README? and can you post output of `git branch`  command

Answer (score 0):

[`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) is a local command which does not push anything.

To avoid any issue, the easiest approach is:

```
git clone https://github.com/<me>/<myRepo>
cd <myRepo>
# report the work you did in your previous repo
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git push -u origin main
```